# How to ensure a new tkinter Toplevel appears on top of all others?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked at the tkinter documentation but am still confused as to how the -topmost option works when multiple Toplevels are open. A simple example:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Toplevel

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Main Window")
root.geometry('1400x900')

top_window = Toplevel(root,bg="lightgray")
top_window.geometry('1400x900')
top_window.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
top_window.wm_title('Top Window 1')

top_window = Toplevel(root,bg="lightgray")
top_window.geometry('1400x900')
top_window.attributes('-topmost','true')
top_window.wm_title('Top Window 2')

root.mainloop()
```

Both Toplevel windows appear on top of the root, but the one labelled Top Window 1 is on top of the one labelled Top Window 2, which is not what I would expect. (Note: For my actual application, I'll be reusing the Toplevel's name over and over, which is why I used the name top_window twice.)

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu, `"Top Window 2"` is always on top.

Comment: On window 11 I experience the same issue.  `"Top Window 1"` is on top of all other windows, however `"Top Window 2"` has `focus`.  I could on change that by replacing the `"true"` with 0 and 1 respectively for the windows.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a Mac (Monterey 12.5.1) and, like you, was also able to get the expected ordering by changing -topmost to 0 and 1, respectively.